# How to pass arguments to an HtmlFile?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

How to pass arguments to an HtmlFile from  C#?

Like: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Sample.html","Arguments");`

If I execute the above code the "Sample.html" file should be opened and it should do something with the "arguments".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Process.Start(
    @"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", 
    "file:///c:/path/to/file/Sample.html?param1=value1"
);
```

---

UPDATE:

To figure out the default browser location:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    public extern static int FindExecutable(
        string forFile, 
        string directory, 
        StringBuilder result
    );

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var browserLocation = new StringBuilder(1024);
        // make sure you specify the correct path and the file actually exists
        // or the FindExecutable will return an empty string.
        FindExecutable(@"d:\work\html\index.htm", null, browserLocation);

        Process.Start(
            browserLocation.ToString(),
            "file:///d:/work/html/index.htm?param1=value1"
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You’ll get +1 as soon as you determine the correct standard browser’s path. ;-)

Comment: But how to get the "value1" in the html file using javascript....

if you dont mind can please explain that too?

Comment: @Pramodh, you may take a look at this article: http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html It shows a function you could use to read parameters passed in the URL.

Comment: :-) fine thank you.... i got an idea... 

var url = window.location.search.substring(1) 

var arr=url.split("=") 

str=arr[1]