# System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() is eating part of my URL

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start`. It's supposed to open `combinedURL`, which basically is a local html file with some extra URL.

```
 string projectPath = C:\Users\d\Desktop\project\start.html
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(projectPath);
                sb.Replace("start.html", "Test_Erkl.html?custid=TST-Pesent&Document=0");

                string combinedURL = Convert.ToString("file:" + "///" + sb);
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(combinedURL);
```

As a result it opens `C:\Users\d\Desktop\project\Test_Erkl.html` instead of `C:\Users\d\Desktop\project\Test_Erkl.html?custid=TST-Pesent&Document=0`. However, if I add `firefox.exe` to it, it works as intended.

```
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("firefox.exe", combinedURL);
```

Why does it cut everything off, after the `?` and how can I make it work without adding `firefox.exe` (or is there something like `defaultbrowser.exe`?)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787987/7571171) for a way to pass parameters to a html file using `Process.Start` and finding out the default browser path.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10504367/1997232)? Why your first approach doesn't work doesn't really matter, it's just not an allowed way. First parameter is executable, anything else should be parameters.